# Rank and Eigenvalue connection

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a square $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$, it is given that the matrix $A^T A$ (where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$) is of rank 2. Deduce that $A^T A$  can never have negative eigenvalue.

I have difficult deducing this..from the rank we know that number of free variables = dimension of nullspace is 1..but how can I make a connection with the eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you mean "deduce that $A^TA$ can never have a negative eigenvalue" or "deduce that $A$ can never have a negative eigenvalue"?

Comment: Have made the edit

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1310715/81360). Rank has nothing to do with it.